# Generic DialogueBox class with different parameters

Tags: c#, singleton, unity3d, user-interface

I have implemented a DialogueBox class which can be static, singleton, service locator, etc.
I have written it as a singleton pattern and implemented it in Unity3d engine. It is a part of a game.
I have ShowDialogueBox method with many parameters. How can I handle it?
The parameters are message, ok button label, cancel button label, has the cancel button or not, actions to be invoked when users click on ok or cancel button.

Is it more suitable to apply Builder pattern for it?

Because the method is not sometimes flexible and I have to provide all parameters.

In addition, my messages are not static and sometimes I need to display a message with parameters like cost value, etc. Therefore, I should add another parameter like params to the method or create the message with params before calling the method?
Also, It is appropriate to pull out Localizer from DialogueBox class?

```
//DialogueBox.GetInstance().ShowDialogueBox("BuyMessage",()=>{},
 //       ()=>{}, "Buy", "Cancel",true)

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text _cancelButtonText;
    [SerializeField] private Text _okButtonText;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _cancelButtonObj;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _okButtonObj;
    [SerializeField] private Text _messageText;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _dialogueBoxObj; //DialogueBox GameObject(Panel)
    private static DialogueBox _instance;

    private Action OKButtonPressedAction = delegate { };
    private Action CancelButtonPressedAction = delegate { };

    public static DialogueBox GetInstance()
    {
        return _instance;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void ShowDialogueBox(string messageKey, Action okButtonPressed,
        Action cancelButtonPressed = null, string okKey = "OK", string cancelKey = "Cancel",
        bool hasCancelButton = true)
    {
        //Localizer manages languages with key/message pair for example: 
        //Localizer.GetInstance().Dictionary[key]---> returns message for the current language

        _messageText.text = Localizer.GetInstance().Dictionary[messageKey];
        _okButtonText.text = Localizer.GetInstance().Dictionary[okKey];
        if (hasCancelButton)
        {
            _cancelButtonObj.SetActive(true); //Show the cancel button
            _cancelButtonText.text = Localizer.GetInstance().Dictionary[cancelKey];
        }
        else
            _cancelButtonObj.SetActive(false);

        OKButtonPressedAction = okButtonPressed;

        CancelButtonPressedAction = cancelButtonPressed;
    }

    public void OnOKButtonPressed() //It is called when a user clicks on OK button
    {
        _dialogueBoxObj.SetActive(false);
         if( OKButtonPressedAction!=null)         
            OKButtonPressedAction();
    }
    public void OnCancelButtonPressed() //It is called when a user clicks on OK button
    {
        _dialogueBoxObj.SetActive(false);
        if(CancelButtonPressedAction!=null)
            CancelButtonPressedAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `gameObject` coming from and where is `Destroy()` coming from?

Comment: MonoBehaviour. It is a built in field referred to the game object owning the script.
It is related to Unity game engine.

Comment: Is there a reason the existing `MessageBox` in the .net library won't work for you?

Comment: I said it is a game with custom UI and art. It is not a win app

Comment: This code looks incomplete. You are not creating the `DialogueBox` anywhere...

Comment: @ t3chb0t. I said, it is related to unity3d. Have you ever worked with unity3d?
In unity, you do not call constructors when objects inherit from monobehaviour. You can create it in the editor(like my way) or in the script(Instantiate).
The code is complete and clear. I do not know where it is unclear.
I have different parameters for Show method that can be default or not. I finally used builder design pattern to handle it. Why -1?! I selected unity3d tag.

Comment: I see that all ask about monobehaviours. Like that I ask about where TcpClient is.
If you are a unity developer, you know about monobeaviour, destroy and other parts of it.

Comment: So, you're saying that mono is magically initializing this field: `private static DialogueBox _instance;`? If this is really the case then I'm ignoring this tag in future because this seems to be one of the stupidest frameworks I've ever seen. Nothing works here as expected. No properties, public fields... no constructor... oh boy.

Comment: @t3chb0t: `_instance` is set in `Awake`, which is a special method in Unity3D.

Comment: @t3chb0t: It is not magical. It is about unity game engine! It creates gameobjects and calls constructors internally. Also, you can create gameobjects in scripts with Instantiate() method. You access to some specific methods like Awake, Start, OnEnable,Update, etc. fired in specific situations like when a gameobject is activated or deactivated or in every frame.
It is not a framework. It is a game engine. My question was not about creating and instantiating at all.

Comment: I understand and I've retracted both my DV and VTC. I also won't comment on [tag:unity3d] anymore. Sorry, my bad - I don't want to see this monstrosity ever again so I'll just ignore this tag in future ;-]